# My desktop doesnt work, i cant close windows the windows look scuffed

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-icons, tabs

Ok so i started my pc today and i think it installed an update(the shut down and restart symbols for example look different) and i cant really use my desktop. Windows like ms teams or firefox or any windows cant be closed. The bar at top of the firefox window is also just not there. The cursor sometimes turns to an x. I cant enter text fields. Tried restarting, cant use normal terminal, cmd alt f2 works tho. Other shortcuts like alt f4 dont work, running softwares still works

Comment: We currently have few clues as to your system, is it Xubuntu 22.10? Xubuntu 22.04 LTS? or something older?  What update was made?  Did you make any changes in the last session before you discovered the issue, why not include some links to screenshots of your issue for us to examine/see. Your question is provided has provided few specific details that allow us to provide meaningful advice.

Comment: Sorry, the version is 20.04.5 lts, i dont think i can take screenshots, i only assumed there was an update im not really sure, just some interface looks different. I didnt do anything last session